# Google Help system

Tags: help-authoring, help-system

I would like to create an HTML help for one of my application, based on the Google help system. Does anyone know whether the Google Help system is available outside Google corp? If yes, how to obtain it. What is the authoring tool? Is it an open  source tool?

If not, is there some authoring tool with the same flavour?

The type of help I would like to produce is the kind you get for instance at 
http://docs.google.com/support/

In particular to have the option to let the user give his/her feedback on the help topic ie.

> Was this information helpful? Yes No
>   Easy to understand? Yes No Complete
>   with enough details? Yes No
>
> Please tell us why you did not find
>   this helpful. Thank you!
>
> How can we make this better? Thank
>   you! Your feedback will help us
>   improve our Help Centre.

Comment: That looks like something I could use as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx is a good authoring tool. http://sphinx-doc.org/